# Is there a convenient autocomplete in unix for previously entered commands like in MATLAB?

Tags: shell, unix, csh

I like how you can autocomplete previous commands in MATLAB by typing a few words and pressing the  key.  The same works in python IDLE. Is there an equivalent of that in unix shells? If it helps, I'm using csh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an alias like so:

```
alias prev 'history | grep \!^'
```

when you type `prev foo`, it searches your history for all occurrences of `foo` and spits out a list like so:

```
23 17:43 foo bar
47 19:29 foo fighters
```

where the first column is the command number, the second is the time it was executed and the last is the command. You can re-execute the previous command by typing `!<command number>`

Answer (score 7):

I don't know in csh, but in bash you have several commands to manipulate the history. In particular, CTRL-R could be useful. See more in:

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/bash/bashref_97.html

Answer (score 2):

In csh, you can access previous commands using [history substitution](http://www.decf.berkeley.edu/help/unix/csh/history.html) (see [`man csh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/csh)).

Examples:

```
% echo $history
% set history=20
% echo a
a
% pwd
/some/dir
% !e
echo a
a
% history
     9  echo a
    10  pwd
    11  echo a
    12  history
% !-3
pwd
/some/dir
% !e:s/a/wow/
echo wow
wow
%
```

Answer (score 0):

`rlwrap` adds gnu readline editing to any console command.

Answer (score 0):

Same as previous answer by Jesus, but with more clarification

Hit `CTRL + R` start typing and voila! (you can hit `CTRL+R` more times to cycle matches)

Double answer but if people are speed reading like me, they will skip the answer since I read words "tool" and saw link I assumed it is 3rd party tool, but it comes built in.